# Hugin how to force stitch panorama photo

Tags: panorama, 360-panorama, hugin

I'm trying to use Hugin to stitch a series of photos taken indoors, sequentially from left to right. However whenever it comes to walls / doorways, even with overlapping features between photos, Hugin has difficulty stitching them together into a single 360 panorama.

I don't really need 100% smooth stitching, even some misalignment is fine. I just need all of the images to be stitched together into a single 360 photo. Is there some way to set Hugin or any other panorama stitching software to "force" stitch all the photos sequentially, regardless of stitching quality?

Thank You!

Comment: Are you setting the control points by hand?

Comment: No I’m just using the default “align” function currently.

Comment: Unless you have made the camera rotate around the ["no-parallax" point](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dMKf1HDaLBo), near and far objects won't match at the same time and that makes it hard for Hugin to find good matches. You can make handled panoramas outdoors, but indoor panoramas require a lot more accuracy.

Comment: I get what you mean, but right now I'm not looking for Hugin to stitch each image perfectly. I just need all of the photos to be stitched together, even if the seams are misaligned. It's for situations where I need to quickly take a rough 360 photo from multiple photos and where the end result doesn't need to be perfect. But I do need them to be stitched together to form a 360 photo.

Comment: Then set control points manually on background/foreground objects only (depending on your needs)

Comment: The problem is that I have quite a lot of images that need to be stitched like this, is there anyway in Hugin where I don’t have to manually set control points for each group of photos I need to stitch?

Comment: You have already used it and it doesn't work....

Comment: If you want to use Hugin's auto functions, the image set needs to be taken properly. If you held the camera at arms length and rotated about your body axis with objects nearby, you will have excessive parallax issues that Hugin can't deal with. At the very least, use a tripod. Best results are rotating the camera about the no parallax point which needs to determined experimentally.